# Haw to make the player stop sliding after a Jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I have a code generated with AI and it makes the player jump to the direction the y axis is pointing to, but I have the problem that when he lands he continues sliding in the direction he jumped to.
Here is the code:

```
public float jumpForce = 10f;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask groundMask;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private bool isGrounded;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Check if the player is on the ground
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    // Get the direction of the player's y axis
    Vector2 direction = transform.up;

    // If the player is on the ground and the jump button is pressed
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        // Add force to the rigidbody in the direction of the player's y axis
        rb.AddForce(direction * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

The AI says that I have to lock the x axis but then I can't jump left and right, only upwards.

Comment: if you're grounded manually apply some friction force, or add a physics material to your player and the ground with a friction value above `0`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I will try it out tomorrow and will let you know if it worked.